How can I link my navbar buttons to my data?
I'm creating a blog and I want to edit and delete blog posts via 2 buttons that I have in my navbar.
However, I'm a getting an error saying that "post is not defined".
Is there a way to make this work?
In my admin dashboard I have my post list:
<div class="posts">
    <ul class="admin-posts">
        <% data.forEach(post => { %>

            <li>
                <a href="/admin-post/<%= post._id %>">
                    <span class="admin-post-title"> <%= post.title %> &nearr; </span>
                </a>
            </li>

        <% }) %>
    </ul>
</div>

And in my header navbar I have my buttons:
<header class="header">
    <div class="header-top">

        <div class="header-button">
            <a href="/logout">
                <svg data-name="Layer 2" id="ac0e4468-8c4e-4c82-ab79-d84fa5e8775a" (...) </svg>
            </a>
        </div>

        <a href="/" class="header-title"><h1>NOTEBOOK</h1></a>
        <p class="header-admin">Welcome, blog owner.</p>

    </div>

    <nav class="header-nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/" class="<%= isActiveRoute("/", currentRoute) %>">
                    <svg data-name="Layer 2" id="Layer_2" (...) </svg>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <form action="/edit-post/<%= post._id %>?_method=PUT" method="PUT">
                    <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="edit-btn">
                    <a href="/edit-post/<%= **post._id** %>" class="<%= isActiveRoute("/edit-post", currentRoute) %>">
                        <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" (...) </svg>
                    </a>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li>
                <form action="/delete-post/<%= **post._id** %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="delete-btn">
                    <a href="/delete-post" class="<%= isActiveRoute("/delete-post", currentRoute) %>">
                        <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" (...) </svg>
                    </a>
                </form>
            </li>


which line was the error thrown from? please log data and see if it has value

I get an error in this line:
<form action="/edit-post/<%= post._id %>?_method=PUT" method="PUT">
The error is: post is not defined
And the data is working on other parts of the project. It's just in this instance that I'm having problems.

Well, you do only declare the post variable in the foreach loop from the dashboard. If there is no variable called post you passed to the render function, or no declaration you didn't include in the code you posted, then it isn't defined. As it seems, there is not just one post variable but more of them in the data object. So, did you intend to have all the post._id of each post in the form of action? Or a button for each post?
